# How to evaluate this integral $\int \frac{6x^{3}+7x^2-12x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I encounter this complex integral today and I don't know how to evaluate it. I have only learnt u-substitution this semester and it seems it is not sufficient to find the primitive function for this integral.
$$\int \frac{6x^{3}+7x^2-12x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}dx$$

How do you evaluate this integral? Is this an eliptic integral or not?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use substitution $x+2 = \sqrt{2}\sinh u$, that is $x=-2+\sqrt{2}\sinh u$.
 Then \begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}& =\sqrt{(x+2)^2+2}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{2}\sinh u)^2 + 2} = \sqrt{2(\sinh^2 u+1)} \\
&\quad = \sqrt{2\cosh^2 u} = \sqrt{2}\cosh u \\
dx &= \frac{d}{du}(-2+\sqrt{2}\sinh u)du = \sqrt{2}\cosh u \,du \\
\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}} &= du \end{align} 
The whole integral is therefore equal to
\begin{align} \int\frac{6x^3+7x^2-12x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}dx &= \int\big(6(-2+\sqrt{2}\sinh u)^3+7(-2+\sqrt{2}\sinh u)^2+\\
&\qquad -12(-2+\sqrt{2}\sinh u) +1\big) du\end{align}
In case you don't know hiperbolic functions:
$$ \sinh u = \frac{e^u-e^{-u}}{2}, \qquad \cosh u = \frac{e^u+e^{-u}}{2}$$
Substituting the formula for $\sinh u$ in the formula above you get an integral where you only need to integrate functions of the for $c e^{ku}$, which should be easy.
To get back to $x$, you can use the formula for the function inverse to $\sinh$:
$$ \text{arsinh }z = \ln (z+\sqrt{z^2+1})$$
so
$$ u = \text{arsinh }\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{2}} = \ln \frac{x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

In general:

When you see $\sqrt{(x-p)^2+q^2}$, try substitution $x-p = q\sinh u$

When you see $\sqrt{(x-p)^2-q^2}$, try substitution $x-p = q\cosh u$

When you see $\sqrt{q^2-(x-p)^2}$, try substitution $x-p = q\sin u$

Whether it works depends on the rest of the integrated function, but it often helps.

Comment: Can you do this in more steps, I don't udnerstand how do you substitute $x+2=\sqrt{2}sinhu$

Comment: the denominator can be expressed as $\sqrt {(x+2)^2 + 2}.$   The substitution $x +2 = \sqrt 2\sinh u$ wil make it equal $\sqrt 2 \cosh u$ and $dx =\sqrt 2 \cosh u\ du$ so they cancel.